# Module AppRegistry is not registered callable module error during the importing native-base shared components outside project

Tags: react-native, native-base

I run into one error today when decided to reuse some components.

I have a few React Native projects and I want to follow DRY principle, as to avoid code duplication. I want to import components to my projects that completely built on 'native-base' library and located outside the project root. However, I'm getting an error:

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhmxJ.png)

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP8t3.png)

Attach:

1. mobile/babel.config.js
2. mobile/metro.config.js

```
// mobile/babel.config.js
const moduleResolverPluginConfig = [
  'module-resolver', {
    alias: {
      'common': '../common'
    }
  }
]

module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [moduleResolverPluginConfig]
}
```

```
// mobile/metro.config.js
const path = require('path')

const commonLibRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../common')
const projectRoot = path.resolve()

module.exports = {
  projectRoot,
  watchFolders: [commonLibRoot],
  resolver: {
    extraNodeModules: {
      'common': commonLibRoot
    }
  },
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting my server works for me when I run into these 'Module AppRegistry is not registered' errors in my project. Try restarting your server

Comment: Thank you for reply, but restarting server doesn't solve issue.

Comment: See if what is mentioned here will help you , check the bottom answer https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2027

Comment: I want to import components are built on native base outside app directory. If you wanna reproduce this, create new project `npx react-native init {name}`, create one more dir (common, shared) on the same level as {name} project and create any component is built on native-base, try to import it. If I import variables, functions I don't see such an error at all. All works fine.